# rvalue for a std::string parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, temporary-objects

What's the difference in practice between LVALUE and RVALUE in the following code when I pass the text?
I mean, in this specific case of a string (where the string is a string literal), is there any benefit of using RVALUE (&&)?

```
void write_Lvalue(const std::string &text) {
    //...
}

void write_Rvalue(const std::string &&text) {
    //...
}

int main() {
    write_Lvalue("writing the Lvalue");
    write_Rvalue("writing the Rvalue");
}
```

Comment: FWIW `const std::string &&text` should not be used.  You defeat the purpose of the rvalue reference by making what it refers to `const`.  If it is `const` it can't be moved from as that is a mutating operation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, constant rvalue reference are not really useful, since you cannot move them. Moving value need mutable references to work.

Let's take your corrected example:

```
void write_lvalue(std::string const& text) {
    //...
}

void write_rvalue(std::string&& text) {
    //...
}

int main() {
    write_lvalue("writing the Lvalue");
    write_rvalue("writing the Rvalue");
}
```

In this case, the two are **completely equivalent**. In these two case, the compiler has to create a string and send it by reference:

```
int main() {
    // equivalent, string created
    // and sent by reference (const& bind to temporaries)
    write_lvalue(std::string{"writing the Lvalue"}); 

    // equivalent, string created
    // and sent by reference (&& bind to temporaries)
    write_rvalue(std::string{"writing the Rvalue"});
}
```

So why have function that takes rvalue references?

It depends on what you do with the string. A mutable reference can be moved from:

```
std::string global_string;

void write_lvalue(std::string const& text) {
    // copy, might cause allocation
    global_string = text;
}

void write_rvalue(std::string&& text) {
    // move, no allocation, yay!
    global_string = std::move(text);
}
```

So why using rvalue reference at all? Why not using mutable lvalue reference?

That is because mutable lvalue references cannot be bound to temporaries:

```
void write_lvalue_mut(std::string& text) {
    // move, no allocation... yay?
    global_string = std::move(text);
}

int main() {
    std::string s = /* ... */;
    write_lvalue_mut(std::move(s)); // fails
    write_lvalue_mut("some text"); // also fails
}
```

But mutable rvalue reference can be bound to rvalue, as shown above.

Comment: A mutable lvalue references also doesn't work with `const` lvalues, and are quite rude to users (who have to assume their variable might get changed by the function).

Comment: In your second example, is `std::move()` even needed? `text` is already an rvalue, so std::string's `operator=(string&&)` method should be invoked anyway.

Comment: @EdwardFalk No, the expression `text` is an lvalue, even if the `text` variable was declared as a rvalue reference. You may want to revise value categories, because you definitely need that move.

Answer (score 4):

There's no benefit in this case. `write_Rvalue` will only accept an rvalue. and `write_Lvalue` will only accept an lvalue.

When you pass a string literal a temporary `std::string` will be constructed from the string literal. The rvalue variant can already bind to this because you're already passing a temporary and the lvalue variant can bind to the temporary because it's `const`.

This for example, will not compile:

```
void write_Lvalue(const std::string &text) {
    //...
}

void write_Rvalue(const std::string &&text) {
    //...
}

int main() {
    std::string a = "hello";
    write_Rvalue(a);
}
```

because we're trying to pass an lvalue `a` to a function only accepting an rvalue.

The benefit that can be gained with rvalue types is that they can be moved from. There's a great post on why moving can be faster [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3109981/1870760).

Making your rvalue `const` defeats the purpose of it though as said in the comments, because it can't be moved from anymore.